# Creating directories Automatically Via Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I'm designing an automation system to publish new software version on windows servers, right now I'm looking for a solution to create new folder/directory based on current folder name and increase the number which has been added at the end of the folder, for example 
my current folder name is
`"c:\wwwroot\folder_1"`, I want to write an script creating new folder named    
 `"c:\wwroot\folder_2"` automatically or
 if my current root folder is `"c:\wwwroot\folder_9"`, it will generate `"c:\wwwroot\folder_10"`.

Indeed I need a script which increase the number at the end of a string value in PowerShell.

would you have any solution to solve this matter?

Comment: This site does not provide scripts or code to member request. You are relatively new here, but this is not your first question, so by now should have read through [ask]. Your question is off topic.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$newfolder = $folder = 'c:\wwwroot\folder_1'
while (Test-Path $newfolder) {
    $newfolder = [regex]::Replace($newfolder,'\d+$',{param($m) [int]$m.Value+1})
}
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $newfolder
```

`$newfolder` is a placeholder used to calculate the next directory number. `$folder` will contain your original directory for any reference you need you later.

`Test-Path` can be used to verify if the suggested directory exists.

Using the `Regex.Replace` method, you can replace the digits (as an integer) with a one number increment. The script block in the `Replace` method allows for the `MatchInfo` object to be passed to `$m` and the corresponding `Value` property can be retrieved.

Comment: @Compo the idea is simple enough for me to not nitpick. I think it covers the idea pretty well. I am sure the required solution is going to be more complex, which cannot be determined without some evidence from the poster. I see it as a step in the right direction rather than an all-encompassing solution. It could actually be helpful for future readers though. The technique I have used is somewhat obscure because online documentation does not make use of the script block with input parameters. It is extremely helpful and more people should know about it.

Comment: I'm not nitpicking, I didn't write the site rules and guidance. That is clear, the OP has made no effort at posting their coding attempts for the task they've laid out in their question. They are therefore, until they've edited their question to include that, asking for someone else to do it for them. That is not what this site is for, or how it works, and you know it.

Comment: @Compo So what is the right move? You want me to delete it so it sits there all pink for most everyone to see anyway? If I don't post it, someone else will anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder, but with relative path not absolute; you need to provide the base name (folder_) and an index (default 1 or any value you desire). Before create the dir, you should check if it exists, and if it exists, you need to assign the last number of the folder name to your index (and increment 1), and create the folder with base name + index number.

Comment: Hi  thanks for your comment, but actually my folders name are not predicted, they might start with "Newfolder_" , "Companyname_" , "Productname_" or ..., I would change my question to      how to increase a number which is at the end of a string? for example I want to change  "myname_2"  to "myname_3" or "school_9" to "school_10" with same script in powershell

Comment: The folder inside the parent folder have all the same name? You can pick the base name and the last number, with a function like substring or similar. You store the number and increase it by one, and you create a string with the base folder + your new index. And its better if you show your code.